# Calculate Column removing brackets on first and last columns. Not working properly as a result

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to use a calculated column to update it's status based on a few "Yes/No" checkboxes. Those fields are "New," "In Progress," "Waiting on Customer," and "Completed." If the checkbox for the respective field is checked then the calculated column should also portray the same. My current code is as follows.

```
=IF([New]=TRUE,"New",IF([In Progress]=TRUE,"In Progress",IF([Waiting on Customer]=TRUE,"Waiting on Customer",IF([Completed]=TRUE,"Completed"))))
```

The problem is that the first and last lose their brackets and the result is only a Yes or No instead of the words "New," "In Progress," etc. When I look at the column again in List Settings it shows like the following. What gives? How can I make this work?

```
=IF(New=TRUE,"New",IF([In Progress]=TRUE,"In Progress",IF([Waiting on Customer]=TRUE,"Waiting on Customer",IF(Completed=TRUE,"Completed"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code as shown below and it worked for me.

```
=IF(New=TRUE,"New",IF([In Progress]=TRUE,"In Progress",IF([Waiting on Customer]=TRUE,"Waiting on Customer",IF(Completed=TRUE,"Completed"))))
```

Set the data type returned from formula as "single line of text"

Comment: My data type was already set to "single line of text." The only response I get is either a "Yes" or a "No." It is supposed to be "New," "In Progress," "Waiting on Customer," "Completed." Thanks for taking the time to take a look at it

Comment: It should work even if your formula is not showing the brackets. When you add the 1st formula in the question, just save it and then add an item. Only one checkbox to be checked at one time. Others need to be unchecked.